# Pointer error when trying to free structure element

Tags: c

I am having an issue freeing the memory associated with an element of an instance of a structure defined as follows:

```
typedef struct WebPage {
  char *url;                               // url of the page
  char *html;                              // html code of the page
  size_t html_len;                         // length of html code
  int depth;                               // depth of crawl
} WebPage;
```

I attempt to free it using:

```
static void setDestroy(set_t *set){

  pair_t *temp2;

  if(set!=NULL&&set->head!=NULL){
    //store the head in a temporary pair
    pair_t *temp = set->head;
    //cycle through LL items, freeing contents and then structure instances
    while(temp!=NULL){
      temp2 = temp->next;
      free(temp->data->url);
      free(temp->data->html);
      free(temp->data);
      free(temp->key);
      free(temp);
      temp = temp2;
    }
    set->head = NULL;
  }

  free(set);
  return;

}
```

However I get this error:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -ggdb   -c -o crawler.o crawler.c
crawler.c: In function ‘setDestroy’:
crawler.c:428:22: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
       free(temp->data->url);
                      ^
crawler.c:428:22: error: request for member ‘url’ in something not a structure or union
crawler.c:429:22: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
       free(temp->data->html);
                      ^
crawler.c:429:22: error: request for member ‘html’ in something not a structure or union
<builtin>: recipe for target 'crawler.o' failed
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing incorrectly? I tried to cast temp->data->url as a string to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the declaration of the `pair_t` type? It looks like `pair_t.data` is `void*`, not `WebPage*`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, pair_t.data is void*.
So how could I cast data to be of type WebPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `temp->data` is `void*`, so you can't use `temp->data->html` and `temp->data->url`. You need to cast it to `WebPage*` to access these members.

```
free(((WebPage*)temp->data)->html);
free(((WebPage*)temp->data)->url);
```